Plotting images from numy in C# using pythonnet
I'm using pythonnet to access numpy in c# i have done all that I wish to do with my data and its running flawlessly the only problem is i dont know how to show the data in c#. This is the very first code ive written in c#. I tried to save the images using matplotlib and try to access the images later but the images aren't saved any where. Does any one know how i can plot these images. Note i dont really care abot matplotlib and any answer would be beneficial.
using Python.Runtime;

namespace ConsoleApp3;

public class ImageRecon
{
    public static void recon(byte[] barr, int dim1, int dim2, int dim3, int dim4, bool correctOverSampling, bool forceOversamplingCorrection)
    {
        string pythonDll = @"C:\Users\Mohsen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python310.dll";
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONNET_PYDLL", pythonDll);
        PythonEngine.Initialize();    
        PythonEngine.BeginAllowThreads();
        using (Py.GIL())
        {
            dynamic builtins = Py.Import("builtins");
            dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
            dynamic sig = Py.Import("scipy.signal");
            dynamic plt = Py.Import("matplotlib.pyplot");
            
            List<dynamic> pycomplexList = new List<dynamic>();
            
            for (int i = 0; i < barr.Length / 2; i += 1)
            {
                double realPart = barr[i];
                double imagPart = barr[(int)(barr.Length/2) +  i];
                dynamic pythonComplex = builtins.complex(realPart, imagPart);
                pycomplexList.Add(pythonComplex);
            }

            dynamic lst = new PyList();

            if (dim1 != 1)
            {
                lst.append(dim1);
            }
            if (dim2 != 1)
            {
                lst.append(dim2);
            }
            if (dim3 != 1)
            {
                lst.append(dim3);
            }
            if (dim4 != 1)
            {
                lst.append(dim4);
            }
            
            dynamic tuple = PyTuple.AsTuple(lst);
            
            dynamic raw = np.array(pycomplexList);
            dynamic k = np.reshape(a: raw.T, newshape:tuple, order:'F');
            if (correctOverSampling & forceOversamplingCorrection)
            {
                k = sig.decimate(k, q:2, ftype:"fir", axis:0);
            }
            var reconImage = np.flip(np.rot90(np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftn((np.fft.fftshift(k))))), axis:0);
            var shape = reconImage.shape;
            builtins.reversed(shape);
            dynamic arr = np.zeros(shape, dtype: "complex");

            for (int i = 0; i < (int)reconImage.shape[-1]; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < (int)reconImage.shape[0]; j++)
                {
                    for (int l= 0; l < (int)reconImage.shape[1]; l++)
                    {
                        arr[i][j][l] = reconImage[j][l][i];
                    }
                }
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < (int)shape[0]; i++)
            {
                plt.axis("off");
                string imagePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "image_" + i + ".png");
                plt.imsave(imagePath, np.abs(arr[i]), cmap: "gray");
            }

            plt.Dispose();
        }
        Py.GIL().Dispose();
    }
}

at first I thought the path wasn't correct so I used path.combine and no difference.
